# Angular PWA: Retaining Motion and Orientation Permissions for Shake Feedback in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, iphone, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently working on implementing a shake-for-feedback feature in my Angular Progressive Web App (PWA) specifically targeting iOS devices. The functionality relies on obtaining Motion and Orientation permissions. I've encountered an issue where, even after the user grants permission, it seems to be forgotten when they leave the app. Consequently, I find myself having to request permission again upon their return.

I'm wondering if there's a way to persist the state of these permissions so that users don't have to repeatedly grant them every time they navigate away from and return to the app. Are there any strategies or best practices for handling and preserving Motion and Orientation permissions in an Angular PWA on iOS?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.